# how to convert the json response into table row content for php

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to build a webpage that would show the stock price in the form of a table. I am using AlphaVantage API for procuring the data.
The PHP code:

```
<?php
$key="demo";
$url="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=".$key;
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result=json_decode($result,true);
if(isset($result['Global Quote'])){
    echo "<table  id='customers' border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Open</th>
                <th>High</th>
                <th>Low</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
                <th>Change Percent</th>
            </tr>";
    foreach($result['Global Quote'] as $key=>$val){
        echo "Need write something here";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}else{
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
?>
```

the json the response for which I want the php code to change is:

```
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "IBM",
        "02. open": "121.6600",
        "03. high": "122.4300",
        "04. low": "118.6100",
        "05. price": "118.8100",
        "06. volume": "5346108",
        "07. latest trading day": "2022-09-30",
        "08. previous close": "121.6300",
        "09. change": "-2.8200",
        "10. change percent": "-2.3185%"
    }
}
```

I think only a change in the echo statement needs to be made after the foreach.
If yes, then what change needs to be made?

Comment: Those are very bad property names and may things will struggle addressing them

Comment: If you want to just output the API response verbatim, including in the order provided, you can use the loop and just output the `$val`, wrapped in `<td>` tags, and make sure a `<tr>` is opened and closed before and after the loop. If you want to control the order, don’t loop, just echo using the provided keys

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is place the `$key` and `$val` into a table row, inside `<td></td>` elements

I assume by the title row in your table, that you dont want all the entries from the JSON so I added an array containing all the valie required columns and just check those with an `in_array()` to decide if that column is required

```
$key="demo";
$url="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=".$key;
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$result=json_decode($result,true);
if(isset($result['Global Quote'])){
    echo "<table  id='customers' border='1'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Open</th>
                <th>High</th>
                <th>Low</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
                <th>Change Percent</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>";
    echo "\n<tbody><tr>";

    // columns from json we want
    $required_cols = ['01. symbol', '02. open', '03. high', '04. low', '05. price', '06. volume', '10. change percent'];
    
    foreach($result['Global Quote'] as $key=>$val){
        if( in_array($key, $required_cols) )  {
            echo "<td>$key</td><td>$val</td>";
        }  
    }
    echo "\n</tr></tbody></table>";
}else{
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
```

RESULT

```
<table  id='customers' border='1'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Open</th>
                <th>High</th>
                <th>Low</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
                <th>Change Percent</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody><tr><td>01. symbol</td><td>IBM</td><td>02. open</td><td>121.6600</td><td>03. high</td><td>122.4300</td><td>04. low</td><td>118.6100</td><td>05. price</td><td>118.8100</td><td>06. volume</td><td>5346108</td>
```